# R - finding mean of list of Ages

Tags: r, mean, lubridate

I'm working with a data frame and looking to calculate the mean age of players debut in baseball.

I can get the answer, however I am a bit confused why I get different outputs doing the same things 2 ways.

Firstly, when I run the below code I get the correct mean:

`mean(as.numeric(players$debut_age)/365, na.rm=TRUE)`

But when I reorganize this as a pipe, it instead only prints the vector of days in debut_age:

`players$debut_age %>% as.numeric()/365 %>% mean(na.rm=TRUE)`

I'm sure there is something simple I'm missing, but I would like to know why these don't produce the same result.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `divide_by`

```
library(dplyr)
players$debut_age %>%       
       as.numeric() %>%
       magrittr::divide_by(365) %>%
       mean(na.rm = TRUE)
```

---

Or place the `as.numeric` with `/` inside a block of `{}`

```
players$debut_age %>% 
      {as.numeric()/365} %>% 
       mean(na.rm=TRUE)
```